# Create an edit button

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sorry, Im fairly new to this and was wondering how to create an edit button as a bar button item...

What I did is I placed a bar button item on the right side of the navigation bar and created an

```
- (IBAction)editButton:(id)sender;
```

I tried to hook this up to the button, but the option doesn't show up. How do I get this button to do something when its clicked?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: +1 for the meta reference :P

Comment: the best way to learn this is to look it up in apple examples. here is a link that describes how the ib action works. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-connections_bindings/CreatingAction.html

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is the way. If you have a view controller "first" and you navigate another view controller "second" by pushing a button or etc. you need to do some work. First you need to create a BarButtonItem in "second" view controller's ViewDidLoad method like this;

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(OnClick_btnBack:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnBack;
[btnBack release];
```

After you do that, you need to write to code for "btnBack" action in the same .m file like this;

```
-(IBAction)OnClick_btnBack:(id)sender  {
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.navigationController.parentViewController animated:YES];
}
```

That's all.

Answer (score 2):

CTRL + click on the bar button item, and drag it to the impementation file of the view controller, viewController.m. Then you would be able to create an IBAction method.